# How to get executing result of a 'DROP' in a custom function in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, index, functions

I have thousands of tables with same structure in a Postgresql database, and each of them has a index with same suffix e.g. '_brok_name'.

I need to drop all those indexes and re-create.
To prevent doing so manually one-by-one, I coded a function to do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dropIndex(
    IN idx_name pg_indexes.indexname%TYPE, OUT successfully boolean)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('DROP INDEX IF EXISTS %s CASCADE;', idx_name );
END
$func$;
```

So I can use it to drop all indexes in one query, like this:

```
SELECT dropIndex(indexname) FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND indexname LIKE '%brok\_name';
```

But I don't know how to get the result of statement `DROP INDEX...` i.e. whether or not it has been executed successfully.

Comment: If no exception is thrown, then it was successful. If it throws an exception something went wrong. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: By the way, you should use `%I` to avoid SQL injection problems.